# Backtracking in regexp faster than expected

Tags: regex, perl, backtracking

According to [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3Epattern%29), the following code should take several seconds to execute:

```
$ time perl -E '$_="((()" . ("a") x 18;  say "ok" if m{ \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)}x;'

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.005s
```

The documentation says:

> Consider how the pattern above detects no-match on
>   `((()aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` in several seconds, but that each extra
>   letter doubles this time.

As seen, it only takes a fraction of a second on my laptop..
Even running with a million `a`'s completes in half a second:

```
$ time perl -E '$_="((()" . ("a") x 1000000;  say "ok" if m{ \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)}x;'

real    0m0.454s
user    0m0.446s
sys 0m0.008s
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The perl compiler may be fixing this for you. Try piping the ((()aaaaaa into standard input instead.

Comment: @ZanLynx Do you mean `echo "((()aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" | perl -nE 'say "ok" if m{ \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)}x;'` ?

Comment: Yes. Or output it from another perl script so you can use the `x 10000`

Comment: @ZanLynx `perl -E 'say "((()" . ("a") x 1000000;' |  perl -nE 'say "ok" if m{ \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)}x;'` runs in half a second too

Comment: Try it with `use re 'debug'` and it'll tell you the steps it's doing to process the `re`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the tricks you can do to figure out what the regex engine is doing, is:

```
use re 'debug';
```

E.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use re 'debug'; 

my $str = "a" x 18;

$str =~ m{ \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)}x;
```

This will then print what the regex engine is actually doing:

```
Compiling REx " \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)"
Final program:
   1: EXACT <(> (3)
   3: CURLYX[0] {1,32767} (40)
   5:   OPEN1 (7)
   7:     BRANCH (20)
   8:       PLUS (37)
   9:         ANYOF[^()][{above_bitmap_all}] (0)
  20:     BRANCH (FAIL)
  21:       EXACT <(> (23)
  23:       STAR (35)
  24:         ANYOF[^()][{above_bitmap_all}] (0)
  35:       EXACT <)> (37)
  37:   CLOSE1 (39)
  39: WHILEM[1/3] (0)
  40: NOTHING (41)
  41: EXACT <)> (43)
  43: END (0)
anchored "(" at 0 floating ")" at 2..2147483647 (checking floating) minlen 3 
Matching REx " \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)" against "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [2..18] gave -1
  Did not find floating substr ")"...
Match rejected by optimizer
Freeing REx: " \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)"
```

If you add your brackets back in, you get a different result - I get around 2000 steps to process the regex. This gets longer with each additional letter - about 300 steps.

So I would say yes - catastrophic backtracking is occurring, but you may well find that processors (and regex engine optimisations) mean the time is considerably shorter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use re 'debug'; 

my $str = "((()"."a" x 100_000;
$str =~ m{ \(([^()]+|\( [^()]* \))+\)}x;
```

Runs considerably longer - but at least a proportion of it is because printing text to the screen is actually quite 'expensive' comparatively.

My test suggests (number of "a"s)

```
10 : 1221 lines of output (broadly correlated with regex steps)
11 : 1324 (+103)
12 : 1467 (+143)
13 : 1590 (+129)
14 : 1728 (+138)
15 : 1852 (+124)

20 : 2630 (approx +155/extra)
30 : 4536 (+190/extra)
40 : 6940 (+240/extra)
50 : 9846 (+290/extra)

100 - 31,846 (+440/extra letter)
```

So certainly looks like exponential behaviour going on - but in neither case, the processing time is still pretty quick, which I'd attribute to faster cpus (and maybe better optimisation of the regex engine)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the `re` pragma..Yes backtracking obviously occurs, but it is considerably faster than what the documentation claims it to be.

Comment: That may be as simple as the documentation being from an older version of perl, and moores law has trumped it.

Comment: @Sobrique - Indeed. That part of the perlre man page is unchanged since perl 5.6.1 (see http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/perl-5.6.1/pod/perlre.pod), and quite possibly earlier. Perl 5.6.1 was released in April, 2001. A decade and a half later, improvements to perl coupled with Moore's Law have made the sentence in question obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

> Consider how the pattern above detects no-match on `((()aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` in several seconds.

This sentence dates back to at least April 2001, when perl 5.6.1 was released. You can see the perlre man page for that release at [search.cpan.org/~gsar/perl-5.6.1/pod/perlre.pod](http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/perl-5.6.1/pod/perlre.pod).

This is perhaps a lesson to be learned here in documenting software. Be careful what you write as your written words will remain unchanged despite years of improvements and multiple forks by others.

Comment: The efficiency point remains valid - it is horribly inefficient to do this, perhaps deceptively so.

Comment: @Sobrique - Exactly. One can easily write a regular expression that takes a long time to execute.